# Removing an element from an array

Tags: c++

I need to remove an element from my profile[] array, then move back all other elements in the array to fill in the now empty space. This is my attempt at doing the first part of the problem, gives a -fpermissive error, Advice?

```
void deleteCreature(int numCreatures, Creatures profile[])

{

for (int x = 0; x < numCreatures; x++)
{
    cout << "The following is a list of all the creatures you take care of:"
        << profile[x].name << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "What creature do you wish to remove?" << endl
        << "CREATURE NAME: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, profile[numCreatures].name);

    std::vector<int> array;

    auto it = std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), profile[numCreatures].name);
    if (it != array.end())
    {
        array.erase(it);
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not find profile!\n";
    }

    cout << "You have removed " << profile[x].name << "." << endl << endl;*/
}
```

}

EDITED

Comment: Use a container insted, like std::vector or std::list. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: It would help if you copy the precise error message.

Comment: @Jepessen while that is good advice in general, this kind of problem is often set as an exercise to students where this is not possible.

Comment: This is not valid C++ code. However, are you sure you don't mean `profile[x]` instead of `profile[num]` in your loop?

Comment: @Jepessen I tried adding that in a previous version and it made the compiler very angry at me.

Comment: `delete` is a C++ keyword. You can't use it as the name function or variable. Choose a different name.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Edited it to make it shorter, thats not actually the name of my function.

Comment: @Baalzamon - Is this a school exercise?  If not, then if you're going to show us std::list code to show us what you want to do, doesn't it make more sense to create a home-made std::list class?  Or even a home-made std::vector class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do people insist on rewriting existing code...

The standard-library does all the work for you:

Version 1:
(only use if you have to use C-Style arrays)

```
std::remove(array,array+arraySize,profile[num].name);
```

Then set the last element to zero and adjust `arraySize`, done.

Version 2:
(the C++ way to do this)

Save the contents of array in an `std::vector`.
You can initialize it from a range, with initializer lists or `push_back()`.

```
std::vector</*whatever type array stores*/> array;
//Initialize array
array.erase(std::find(array.begin(),array.end(),profile[num].name));
```

The `vector`keeps track of its size and allocated memory automatically, so you canot get it wrong.

If you are not sure the profile exists, test `result_of_find != array.end()` before you erase, in the first version check `result_of_remove == arraySize - 2`.

For example in version 2:

```
std::vector<int> array;
//Initialize array
auto it = std::find(array.begin(),array.end(),profile[num].name);
if (it != array.end()){
    array.erase(it);
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Could not find profile!\n";
    //Handle error
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> array;
  result_of_find != array.end();
  array.erase(std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), profile[numCreatures.name]));`      Like this?

Comment: `std::vector<int> array;` Does this initialize the array?

Comment: compiler says 'vector' is not a memeber of 'std' derp derp fixed it didnt add the header

Comment: In a sense yes, but the default constructed vector is empty. You can fill it for example like `std::vector<int> array = {1,2,3,4};`. `array`now contains the elements 1,2,3 and 4 in that order. You need to `#include <vector>` to use it. For more information on `vector`see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Could i populate that array with another array earlier in the program, such as where profile[numCret].name is stored?

Comment: Yes you can, read the page I linked (especially the constructor part).

Comment: `vector<int> const(&profile[0], &profile[numCreatures]);` Kind of like this?

Comment: This being what I've commented above?